# How can i use jwt callback and session callback for role-based auth?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm new to Next Js and trying to write role-based authorization with Next Auth, but I'm facing a problem with session and token return.

```
export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. 'Sign in with...')
      name: 'Credentials',
      // The credentials is used to generate a suitable form on the sign in page.
      // You can specify whatever fields you are expecting to be submitted.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
      credentials: {
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
        email: {label: "email", type: "email"}
      },
      async authorize(credentials, request): Promise<any> {

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {email: request.body?.email}
        })

        if(!user || !user.password) {
          throw new Error("User not found")
        }

        // If no error and we have user data, return it
        const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(request.body?.password, user?.password)
        if(!checkPassword) {
          throw new Error('Invalid Password')
        }
        return {email: user.email, name: user.name, role: "USER"}
      }
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      profile(profile) {

        return {
          id: profile.sub,
          name: profile.given_name,
          email: profile.email,
          image: profile.picture,
          role: "USER"
        }
      },
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string
    })
  ],
  session: {strategy: "jwt"},
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({token, user, profile}): Promise<any> {
      const dbUser = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {email: token.email}
      })
      
      if(!dbUser) {
        console.log(user)
        return {
          id: profile?.sub,
          name: profile?.name,
          email: profile?.email,
          picture: profile?.image,
          role: user?.role
        }
      }
      
      return {
        id: dbUser.id,
        name: dbUser.name,
        email: dbUser.email,
        picture: user?.image,
        role: user?.role
      }
    },
    async session({token, session}) {
        if(token) {
          session.user.id = token.id
          session.user.name = token.name
          session.user.email = token.email
          session.user.image = token.picture
          session.user.role = token.role
        }

        return session
      
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    signOut: "/dashboard"
  }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

Here is my configuration. when I log in with credentials, the authorize function should be executed, which finds the user and returns it. in the async jwt function, it searches for the user in the database, which means that the user is logged in with Google and we use user to pass the data to the token. If the user exists, then we return the data taken from the database, but "role: user?.role" becomes undefined, although if we display the user in the console before returning, we will first get all the necessary data: "{
name: 'last',
email: 'lvuucayy@gmail.com',
role: "USER"
}", but then console.log(user) is triggered again and why now it returns undefined and it is undefined that is returned to the token and then to the session. The question is, why does user become undefined, although the first data contains everything you need to correctly create a token